# Length of String

Tags: c++, c

String manipulation problem

http://www.ideone.com/qyTkL

In the above program (given in the book C++ Primer, Third Edition By Stanley B. Lippman, Josée Lajoie  Exercise 3.14) the length of the Character pointer taken is len+1

```
char *pc2 = new char[ len + 1];
```

http://www.ideone.com/pGa6c
However, in this program the length of the Character pointer i have taken is len

```
char *pc2 = new char[ len ];
```

Why is there the need to take the length of new string as 1 greater when we get the same result. Please Explain.

Mind it the Programs i have shown here are altered slightly. Not exactly the same one as in the book.

Comment: Are you sure one of the two isn't using strlen(string) + 1? strlen gives the length of the string EXCLUDING the `'\0'`. Quite often when you use strlen you add the +1 in the line of the strlen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To store a string of length n in C, you need n+1 `char`s. This is because a string in C is simply an array of `char`s terminated by the null character `\0`. Thus, the memory that stores the string "hello" looks like

```
'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '\0'
```

and consists of 6 `char`s even though the word hello is only 5 letters long.

The inconsistency you're seeing could be a semantic one; some would say that length of the word hello is len = 5, so we need to allocate `len+1` `char`s, while some would say that since hello requires 6 `char`s we should say its length (as a C string) is `len=6`.

Note, by the way, that the C way of storing strings is not the only possible one. For example, one could store a string as an integer (giving the string's length) followed by characters. (I believe this is what Pascal does?). If one doesn't use a length field such as this, one needs another way to know when the string stops. The C way is that the string stops whenever a null character is reached.

To get a feel for how this works, you might want to try the following:

```
char* string = "hello, world!";
printf("%s\n", string);
char* string2 = "hello\0, world!";
printf("%s\n", string2);
```

(The assignment `char* string = "foo";` is just a shorthand way of creating an array with 4 elements, and giving the first the value 'f', the second 'o', the third 'o', *and the fourth* '\0').

Comment: @Xaero: You just don't observe any problems. Yet. It will break in some subtle way when you least expect.

Comment: @Xaero, depends on length of input string, if you set `len` to 5, and you pass in "Hello", the problem is that there is no where to store the `\0`, if you pass in "foo", there is space.

Comment: @Xaero: Because whenever you cross the boundary of an array, it is ubdefined behavior, which means, the program can crash, act normally, order pizza, and do whatever else it wishes too... technically :)

Comment: Why does anyone need to add something extra?? When the length is same in both cases??? If it needs to be added in second then that would mean the previous did not have the null ('\0') character!

Comment: @Acme: That's a convention - there has to be that null character so that whoever manipulates the string knows where it ends.

Comment: @Acme It is just a convention. if your Array is of chars and it terminates with a '\0' then it is a string. Something a human might want to read. Else it is just a bunch of bytes of sizeof(char) that you can acces bytewise. All functions that work with strings expect it to be '\0' (zero-)terminated. Functions that operate on arrays of bytes expect a length parameter to tell you how long it is. But that is just a convention used in C and C++. Btw since this is c++ you should be using std::string for strings and std::vector<char> for char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's a convention that the string is terminated by an extra null character so whoever allocates storage has to allocate `len + 1` characters.

Answer (score 0):

It causes problem. But, sometimes, when `len` isn't aligned, the OS adds some bytes after it, so the problem is hidden.